# Is there any difference between closed and open NURBS on control and knots?

Tags: spline, nurbs

I am wondering if there is any difference between closed and open nurbs on control and knots.

I checked many documents, but cannot find the exact answer, so asked here.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no difference in terms of control points and knot sequences for open or closed nurbs curves. They both follow the rule "number_of_knots = number_of_control_points + order". However, closed nurbs curves (or periodic nurbs curves) are achieved by having some special arrangement for the control points and knot sequence. For example, the knot sequence [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] with 7 control points (P1, P2,...to P7) will result in an open cubic B-spline curve. If we change the knot sequence into [ -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75] and make P5=P1, P6=P2 and P7=P3, then the curve will become a periodic cubic B-spline curve with C2 continuity at the joint.

Comment: what is the formula for determining whether a nurbs curve is closed?

Comment: @fang If I run the spline from t=0 to t=1 under your formulation will that run me through the original starting and ending points without "wrapping around"?

Comment: @nonremovable: Yes. If you evaluate the spline from 0 to 1, then you will not see "wrap-around".

Comment: @fang.  Does this method work if my control points were generated such that the resulting curve interpolates a data set that I had?  I used the algorithm from The NURBS book page 369 "GlobalCurveInterp" to interpolate a dataset.  But I want to make the resulting curve closed, and the book is silent on this.  In other works, I would like to make the curve closed (with C2 continuity) but keep it so that it still interpolates the data.

Comment: @nonremovable: Yes. It will work. To interpolate N points with a periodic cubic B-spline of C2 continuity, the B-spline needs to have (N+3) control points.  You also need to set up the knot sequence similar to the 'style' in my post and add 3 compatibility equations to your interpolation equation set to make sure that the last 3 control points are the same as the first three control points. For further questions on this topic, please post a question in SO.

Comment: Will this method work when the knot vector is nonuniform from u_p to u_(m-p)? (where m+1 is the number of knots). Also, is there a way to figure out the value `t` in which a particular control point has the most influence? I noticed that P1 is most influential at different offsets depending on the degree.

Comment: This method will work for nonuniform knot vector as well. The other question seems like unrelated to original post and therefore no comments here.  Please post a separate question if you would like to get feedbacks.