# Make an interpolating B-spline curve closed with C2 continuity while retaining the interpolation of the points

Tags: c++, interpolation, bspline

This post is a continuation of the comment section of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747720/is-there-any-difference-between-closed-and-open-nurbs-on-control-and-knots/24752173?noredirect=1#comment73399232_24752173)  I have implemented the algorithm `ALGORITHM A9.1 GlobalCurveInterp` from *The NURBS Book* (2nd edition) which calculates an interpolating B-spline given a set of points Q.  I would like to make this spline closed with C2 continuity at the joining point while continuing to have the curve interpolate the points.  I have looked at many websites and books which all suggest "Control Point Wrapping" or "Knot Wrapping" but without going into details or giving an example of what to do.  If anyone can point me to a resource or describe in detail an algorithm of how to do this, I would much appreciate it.  Given the points Q, the interpolating algorithm returns control points P as well as the knots U (using chord-length method) for the B-spline curve.  Do I need to modify these control points and knots *before* or *after* running the interpolation algorithm, and in what way?  Thank you.  I am using C++ if it matters.